# The append operation of list

Tags: python, list, append

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param nums: A list of Integers.
    @return: A list of permutations.
    """
    def permute(self, nums):
        # write your code here
        result = []
        if nums is None:
            return result
        self.permution(nums, 0, result)
        return result

    def permution(self, array, k, result):
        if k == len(array):
            print array
            result.append(array)
        else:
            for i in xrange(k, len(array)):
                array[i], array[k] = array[k], array[i]
                self.permution(array, k+1, result)
                array[i], array[k] = array[k], array[i]

if __name__=="__main__":
    print Solution().permute([1, 2, 3])
```

This is my code about permutations. When I output the answer, I found the problem.

If I use `print array`,the output is

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

and it's right. But when I use `result.append(array)`,the output is

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I don't understand why it's not the same.

Comment: Is your question really *"why is `print`ing something not the same as `.append`ing it to a `list`"*? If so, **why would it be?!**

Comment: why don't you use the itertools version?

Comment: I mean I print the array is like that,but i append it to the result, the result's element is not the same as the print element， i don't understand this ，Thank you！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple call_by_reference issue. You are passing the `array` by reference not by value in each recursion. Since the `array` is passed by reference the changes in any recursive step applies to all sub-arrays in `result` because each sub-array is a reference of the same array. To get the correct result do as follows:

Replace:

```
self.permution(array, k+1, result)
```

with:

```
self.permution(array[:], k+1, result)
```

For more details on the topic see [passing arguments](http://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php).

Comment: Why have you put the horrible formatting back in?! Apart from `array` and `result`, those things **are not code**.